# Does converting a protobuf-net stream to base64 undo the perf and size benefits of protobuf?

Tags: c#, base64, protobuf-net

I just started using the protobuf library to do permanent global caching of some expensive queries. I'm storing it in a text field in MSSQL and a memo field in MSAccess and will be extending it to Sqlite next, so I am reluctant to use a binary field unless I have to-- I figure string manipulations will work better cross db than binary.  It seems like the ToBase64String step undoes the various benefits of protobuf (size, speed, memory usage).

```
public void StoreInDb(T dataPoints, string parameters, string queryName)
{
    //Store in cache
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    Serializer.Serialize(stream, dataPoints);
    byte[] data = new byte[stream.Length];
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
    string output = Convert.ToBase64String(data); //Meh, not pretty
    using (CacheInsert inserter = new CacheInsert())
    {
        inserter.Insert(parameters, output, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), queryName);
    }

}
```

Any suggestions on how to do this better faster cheaper?

Comment: Another important question here is perhaps: "compared to...?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid a duplicate of the data by using:

```
string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(
       stream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)stream.Length);
```

The base-64 adds a *little* overhead, but should usually be fine. If your string data-type is UTF-16, note that it will double the size again, of course.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try to store the data in binary format and only fall back to storing as a string where binary data types are not allowed (if there are actually any).  If you must convert to a base-64 string however, you won't be undoing all of the benefits of protobuf; the result would still be more compressed than if you had converted the original raw data to base64.